# Chrome Profile Running on Another PC?

Tags: google-chrome

Yesterday, I switched my computer name from 'Inspirational' to 'Skybbles'. Today, I got an error message from Chrome that my profile was running on another 'pc', 'Inspirational'. Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: Your question title "Has anyone encountered this, here is why" is poor. It has no information about the problem. Why would anyone read it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you did, then here's why.

Chrome sticks to the computer name that you had when you first installed it. That means, it expects to be run **only** on that computer with that name. To Chrome, that computer name = a machine. So when you switch names, Chrome thinks that it has been moved to another computer, but in reality, your machine's name has only changed. Therefore, it also thinks that its old copy is still running on the other machine, so it gives you the error. That message is completely fine, Chrome is just telling you to finish its transitioning process.